# Compilation matconvnet - vl_compilenn

Tags: matlab, compiler-errors, matlab-compiler

I am using 64bit MATLAB trial R2015b in Linux mint. I am trying to compile the CPU version of the library. When I try to configure compiler for mex using command

```
mex -v GCC='/usr/bin/gcc-4.7' timestwo.c
```

It shows me an error

```
In file included from /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/extern/include/mex.h:51:0,
from /home/tt/Desktop/practice/timestwo.c:1:
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015b/extern/include/matrix.h:23:20: fatal error:    
stdlib.h: No such file or directory       
compilation terminated.
```

As it is not compiled. So,

```
cd /home/tt/Desktop/practice/matconvnet-1.0-beta14/matlab/
vl_compilenn

Error using mex
No supported compiler or SDK was found.

Error in vl_compilenn>mex_compile (line 438)
mex(mopts{:}) ;

Error in vl_compilenn (line 400)
mex_compile(opts, srcs{i}, toobj(bld_dir,srcs{i}), flags.mexcc) ;
```

Comment: Did you run `mex -setup` to configure  a compiler?

Comment: Yes, it said mex is configured with gcc